# Is Perfection better without or with it?

Tags: theology, emotions

The pattern goes that G-d does not need our prayers, or anything tangible or intangible because He has no need whatsoever as the Primal cause and His perfection. He cannot gain from anything.

Under this assumption, we shun anything like tenderness, desire for relationship and emotions when speaking  of G-d's attributes of perfection.

Would not it be perhaps the opposite that contributes to G-d's unfathomable perfection ?

I wonder if G-d's longing for goodness, relationship, connection, and thousands of valuable feelings and emotions, is not the motive for His Creation and Torah, the signature of His almighty perfection_ the Plus, despite our common belief G-d cannot change or improve himself ?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking.

Comment: Shomer Emunim asks this in vikuah rishon

Comment: The pattern goes that G-d does not need our prayers, or anything tangible or intangible because He has no need whatsoever as the Primal cause and His perfection. He cannot gain from anything. My question means to tackle this assumption and query the possible origin of emotions in G-d's perfection and a facet of His desire for Creation and Torah

Comment: This is not true. Judaism is not as uniform as you present it in "we". Many approaches in Judaism present G-d as longing for connection, relationship, goodness etc.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate. I suspect you are asking an excellent question with some fascinating answers. To get reopened, you need to edit your wuestion directly using the tiny gray edit button under the questions “theology” tag. Unfortunately, comments don’t count gor much.

Comment: I don't understand how this question is unclear